# What does this sentence about 'ὑπό' mean?

Tags: etymology, meaning

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%91%CF%80%CF%8C) has the description of meaning for the *ancient Greek* word 'ὑπό':

> under, that is, (with the genitive) of place (beneath), or with verbs
>   (the agency or means, through); (with the accusative) of place
>   (whither [underneath] or where [below]) or time (when [at]): among,
>   by, from, in, of, under, with. In compounds it retains the same
>   genitive applications, especially of inferior position or condition,
>   and specifically covertly or moderately.

I cannot grasp the *exact* meaning of this sentence. I do not mean the terms, my problems are with identifying what are **the scope for the respective 'or' words**. 
Could you help me comprehend it?

**note** I may better ask this on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), but in case the sentence is 'genuinely ambiguous', I don't know how much linguistic background is given on ELL.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is, properly formatted:

- ***under***, that is,

  - (with the genitive) of place (*beneath*),
    or with verbs (the agency or means, *through*);
  - (with the accusative) of place (whither [*underneath*] or where [*below*])
    or time (when [at]): *among, by, from, in, of, under, with*.
  - In compounds it retains the same genitive applications,
    especially of inferior position or condition,
    and specifically covertly or moderately.

This is a dictionary definition, which means that it's a list, giving English words that it might mean, and that complete sentences are only used when necessary, as in the last item. In the first items, there are differences depending on what construction it's being used in.

Just like many English words; for instance ***over*** -- *over that hill* may refer
**either** to an airplane's position or to a village's position, depending on the construction it finds itself in.

By the way, Greek ***ὑπό*** is cognate to Latin ***sub*** (and Greek ***ὑπέρ*** is cognate to Latin ***super***).
PIE initial *s- changed to /h/ in Greek, but stayed /s/ in Latin. Details [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/howtoreadgreek.pdf).

Comment: Tiny correction: while it's true initial s yielded h in Greek, there never was an initial s in this word in Greek—it is directly from _upo_ with automatic aspiration of initial u except in dialects where this does not happen and the form is _υπό_ (with no aspiration, though the spiritus lenis apparently cannot be typed on my phone). _Sub_ in Latin is from _ex-upo_ (with regular pretonic voicing of non-initial p and subsequent syncope).